# How to prevent submit/ng-submit event from triggering when using multiple buttons inside a form

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

Clicking take photo button that performs the function `getPhoto()`, the form performs the function of `funcSubmit()` `ng-submit` automatically.
What would need to change to prevent this from happening? It performs only the function `getPhoto()` without running `ng-submit` the form.

Ps .: This code is part of an app android mobile, developed with ionic framework

```
<ion-view title="OS">
    <form ng-submit = "funcSubmit()">
        <ion-content class="has-header"> 
            <ion-list >
                <ion-item >
                    <button name="fota" class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="getPhoto()">
                        <i class="icon ion-ios7-camera"> Photo</i>                      
                    </button>
                </ion-item >
            </ion-list >
        </ion-content>
        <div class="bar bar-footer bar-stable">
            <button name="canc" class="button button-light" ui-sref="app.padronis">Cancel</button>
            <button name="subm" class="button button-light" type="submit">Save</button>     
        </div>
    </form>      
</ion-view>
```

Thanks for all...

Comment: Please share your controller code

Comment: Do you mean that your form submits on clicking the Get Photo button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use :

```
<input type="button" name="fota"  ng-click="getPhoto()">
```

Because `<button>` automatically call ng-submit.

Comment: I'm try but that way did not call the "getPhoto()" function.

Comment: I remove the tags "forms" from my source and keep all tags "button", but i use ng-click in all buttons... inclusive button submit. Thats ok now. it's works fine.

Answer (score 11):

> Because button automatically call ng-submit.

I believe this is more about the **type** attribute of your buttons, than the button **tag** itself.

I guess default is *submit* and your browser is triggering submit because you ommited the (required?) type attribute.
One should try `<button type="button"></button>` along with a `<button type="submit"></button>`.

Those are assumptions, but every time I wonder how Angular deals with HTML, I always choose semantic and it just works. This case shouldn't be an exception.

Answer (score 4):

```
<button type="button"..>
```

Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

In an angular form you are only meant to have one button - this calls ng-submit.

If you want to have multiple button-like elements, you will need to style a div or input to look like a button.

For example:

```
<div class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="getPhoto()">
    <i class="icon ion-ios7-camera"> Photo</i>                      
</div>
```

Comment: Is better to use a `<button>` tag for many usability reasons. See here why: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZGqnp06DnI (Just use button)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is in one of my current Ionic apps:

```
    <form name="myForm">
        <div class="item">
            <button class="button button-block button-positive icon-left ion-ios7-camera" ng-click="takePicture()">Camera</button>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <button class="button button-block button-positive icon-right ion-chevron-right" ng-click="update(obj)">Upload</button>

        </div>
    </form>
```

There are two javascript functions, one to take the picture and another using:

```
ft.upload($scope.mypicture, encodeURI(Urlforupload), uploadSuccess, uploadError, options);
```

to upload the picture and some form fields. Most of this work is borrowed from: https://github.com/yafraorg/ionictests who deserves more of the credit than myself.